# React says I'm missing a semicolon, but where?

Tags: reactjs, syntax

I have looked at my code over and over, but cannot for the life of me figure out where my syntax error is occurring. React says I'm missing a semicolon in line 15 of my code [here](https://snack.expo.io/lb8hEIgLN) and would really appreciate another pair of eyes to look at this for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong when using `Let` keyword. It must be `let`.

Answer (score 1):

your `Let` should be written in small letter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing semicolon on line 17, as part of an object started on line 15.

[image]

Comment: the error is still there after I added it, I've tried it already